# Convert Array for mySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries. The first one is generating a list of ids (col_id_8) I want to use in the second query. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT col_id_8 FROM exp_channel_grid_field_84 WHERE entry_id = :entry_id';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    try {
        $stmt->execute(array('entry_id' => $entry_id));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $fullcodes[] = $row['col_id_8'];
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) { error_log($e->getMessage(),0); }

    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT name FROM stix_live_orders WHERE code in (:allcodes) ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 4';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    try {
        $stmt->execute(array('allcodes' => $fullcodes));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        # MORE CODE
    }
```

Comment: you can do this in a single query using a subselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$stmt->execute(array('allcodes' => implode( ',', $fullcodes ) ));` instead `$stmt->execute(array('allcodes' => $fullcodes));`

Comment: For some reason it didn't work there, but when I put it in the prepared statement it worked like a charm! Since this is a contained area, I'll just leave it :) Thank you!